# Schedule Publish Phases Separately Datepicker allows picking up previous date

Tags: publishing, cme, publishtransaction

In the options for `publishing`, when I select the "Schedule Publish Phases Separately" and I select "Generate Publishable Content Now" and then "Place Content Online Later". The datepicker allows the **previous date** to be selected for "Place Content Online Later". 
Is this a known issue? Anybody experienced the same issue? This happens only with "Schedule Publish Phases Separately" option. On the "Publish Content Later" option I am not able to pick a previous date.

We are on Tridion 2013 SP1.

**Update:**

After few hit and trials, I found the exact steps to reproduce. This is happening in all browsers. Here are the exact steps:

1. On first item schedule using the Schedule Phases Separately, it works as expected and does not allows to select the previous date.
2. But after that if we schedule another item, the datepicker is already filled with the date and then it allows to pick up a previous date (any previous date) in the Schedule Publish Phases Separately option.

It is reproducible on  Chrome, IE, FF or Safari. If I pick up a previous date, the transaction is executed immediately.

Comment: is your server and local date or timezone same?

Comment: All servers are in same time zone (UTC)

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your question. Are you saying that you can pick a time in the past (but on the same day)? Or are you saying that you can also pick a day in the past? Also, which version of Tridion is this?

Comment: I have added details in the question. I can pick any previous date on "Schedule Publish Phases Separately" option

Comment: And the result is that deploying will happen at the same time as publishing?

Comment: I can't reproduce that. Which browser are you using? And do you have HR1 installed?

Comment: i also cannot reproduce this in 2013 SP1, 2013 SP1 HR1. I can choose an earlier time for deploying than publishing and that becomes a normal publishing action and not scheduled. Also tested in different browsers but cannot choose a date in the past. Do you have any extension on the CME that could be interfering with this?

Comment: @NunoLinhares yes the transaction is published immiditaely

Comment: @PeterKjaer I have updated the browser details

Comment: Ah, the date being saved from a previous scheduled publishing is the crucial missing piece. Maybe you could put the fact that it's been confirmed as a defect in an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Tridion Support team have been able to reproduce the same and confirmed that this a defect and have sent it over to R&D. It is happening in 2013 SP1 and SP1 HR1 as well. Once I receive a hotfix, I will update my answer.

As a word of caution, I will like to suggest everyone to watch out date selected because I noticed this behavior when I was trying to set a time sensitive publish for the next day 1200, but by default the previous day was selected and I just went ahead with time changes assuming it cannot be a back date. When the jobs started to go from "Scheduled for Publish" and forward to the next stage is when I realized there is a problem and I deleted the jobs from the queue, just in time!!